# How to pass Parameters to stored procedure with input parameters from checkboxes

Tags: dynamic-sql

I have a query where i need to generate results based on checkbox selection. How do i need to pass my input parameters to the stored procedure in the where condition based on selection.

Note: i may select one check  box else all of them depending on my need, the query needs to dynamically adjust and give me my result set

Comment: What does "Dynamically adjust" mean to you?  Since you list `dynamic-sql` that indicates that you are building different queries, based on the 'checkbox' selections.  You need to spell this out more if you expect a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass one paramter for one Checkbox and set the default value of the paramter as `NULL` in Stored procedure.

So for 5 checkbox you can go for 5 optional parameter, while executing stored procedure pass only those parameter for which checkbox is checked. Pass 2 parameter incase two checkbox is checked and so on.

Now in stored procedure, you can handle query parameter wise. Default `NULL` you can treated as unchecked checkbox